# Java: use URL object for File object

Tags: java, file, url

I want to read some data for my app. Here my code:

```
 URL url = Myclass.class.getResource("/data/file.txt"); //Myclass is my class name
    File file = new File(url.toString());  //maybe I met error here. 
//File Constructor just receive String object, I don't know how to convert
    FileInputStream reader = new FileIputStream(file);
```

I don't know how to change url to File to read it. Please tell me how to solve.

Thanks :)

Comment: Looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006098/unable-to-read-a-text-file-from-another-machine/10006188#10006188 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read a resource as if it were a file. The following syntax should work:

```
InputStream resource = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/data/file.txt");
```

To avoid relative / absolute path issues, you can also use:

```
InputStream resource = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/data/file.txt");
```

Comment: I meet error: FileNotFound Exception, although I'm sure that file.txt in data folder

Comment: How about `getResourceAsStream("data/file.txt");`? (without the leading ``/``)

Comment: Yes. I still meet this error. I can use `getresource` when I load an image:`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(View.class.getResource("/data/icon.png"));`

Comment: See my edit. You can also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873960/getresourceasstream-not-working-for-every-class

Comment: *"although I'm sure that file.txt in data folder"*  Test it by **looking inside the Jar**.  (Sheesh..)

Comment: *"Not sure why this got downvoted?"*  (Is not a question, so needs no question mark.)  As to "Why did this get down-voted?"  well.. that is a good question.  Would the down-voter care to share their reasoning?

Comment: I didn't downvote it but I don't see how the second form "avoid[s] relative/absolute path issues".

Comment: The way I understand it, the class loader will try to find the resource in the classpath. Correct me if I'm wrong.